# Support multiple screen sizes in Android with just one layout

Tags: android

I read something about supporting multiple screen sizes in Android.
For that most of the answers recommended to create different layouts
 (layout-normal, layout-small, and so on). But that would mean that
I have to define all my layouts multiple times. I don't think that
this is a smart solution.

Is there no way to create just one layout and to automatically scale
it for any display size?

Comment: `Is there no way to create just one layout and to automatically scale it for any display size?` I normally do so. **Rarely** I need to define a different layout. Mostly I need to specify a different layout for portrait and landscape modes.

Comment: You can take 9 Patch images and design your layout in relative way rather than defining the size static i.e fix dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several parameters in layouts in android that adapt themselves to the size of the screen (fill_parent, center...), however I have not seen in android's layout parameters for everything... for example 1/3 of width.

Finally what I am doing is the following:

- One layout per architecture of the interface. For example, in tablets I change the architecture, integrating sometimes 2 layouts in one.
- Include, programmatically, changes of sizes. For example, an button I want to be 1/3 of the screen I need to programmatically obtain the width of the screen and change the button size.
- Always include several sizes of icons that android automatically selects depending on resolution.

But there is a significant part of the job that needs to be done "by hand".